# Implementing recyclerview holder view size change when scrolling another recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have in my app a fragment that has 2 Recyclerview - one horizontal and one vertical.

I am trying to implement an "animation" that changes the horizontal RV's views height and width according to my vertical RV's scroll position.

Here is my implementation of NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() -

```java
featuredProductsNestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener((NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener)
                (nestedScrollView, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY) -> {

                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "scrollY - " + scrollY);
                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "oldScrollY - " + oldScrollY);
//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "-----------------");

                    int calculatedValueFrom = scrollY;
                    if (scrollY == 0)
                        calculatedValueFrom = oldScrollY;
                    else if (oldScrollY == 0)
                        return;

//                    if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
//                        calculatedValueFrom = scrollY;
//                    } else {
//                        calculatedValueFrom = oldScrollY;
//                    }

//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "calculatedValueFrom - " + calculatedValueFrom);

                    int vendorsRowItemHeight = Math.max(160 - calculatedValueFrom, 80);
//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "vendorsRowItemHeight - " + vendorsRowItemHeight);
//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "scrollY - " + scrollY);

                    int newWidth = (int) (303 * (vendorsRowItemHeight / 160f));
                    int newHeight = vendorsRowItemHeight - 10;


//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "newWidth - " + newWidth);
//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "newHeight - " + newHeight);
//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "-----------------");


                    int newHeight1 = newHeight * 5;
                    int newWidth1 = newWidth * 5;

//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "newHeight1 - " + newHeight1);
//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "-----------------");
//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "newWidth1 - " + newWidth1);
//                    Log.d("scrollYValue", "-----------------");

                    resizeView(vendorsList, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, newHeight1);
                    resizeView(featuredVendorsNestedScrollView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, newHeight1);

                    for (int i = 0; i < currentVendorsList.size(); i++) {
                        VendorsHolder holder = (VendorsHolder) vendorsList.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                        if (holder != null) {
                            resizeView(holder.vendorHolderCardview, newWidth1, newHeight1);
                            vendorsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

```java
private void resizeView(View view, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        try {
            Constructor<? extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams> ctor = view.getLayoutParams().getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, int.class);
            view.setLayoutParams(ctor.newInstance(newWidth, newHeight));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have some weird behaviour going on in my app when this function works - it does resize the top horizontal RV's views, but for every scroll being made the `scrollY` value gets rested to 0 so the animation has the feeling of a flickering animation (which is actually not true, it actually does what I wanted but for some reason goes back to the minimal value possible)

here is an image of my log prints of `scrollY` so you can better understand what I mean -

[image]

So basically, for some reason, the `scrollY` value represents something other than just the value going down...otherwise how can I explain why it resets itself for every time the function is being called?

Comment: `RecyclerView`s scroll is handled by its `layoutManager`. When you resize it, `layoutManager` decides it's current scroll offset will no longer be valid. So it stores current scroll of first visible item, resets scroll back to 0 and recalculates layout starting from first visible item then reapplies stored scroll.

Comment: @Pawel So how can I bypass it and get a solid up/down value with no "bumps"?

Comment: hey @Pawel, any ideas about this one?

Comment: What about looking into coordinator layout as parent view group for both recyclers? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout

Comment: @ThomasCook why would that make any differents?

Comment: It's used to coordinate the behaviour between child views. I'm not 100% sure it will work for your use case (hence why I haven't written up a full blown answer to your question), but I think it could be used to have the height of one view be driven by another, by using the coordinator layout to coordinate this behaviour.

Comment: There are a lot of articles on how to use it to drive heights of views as function of scrolling another view. https://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html
https://blog.mindorks.com/using-coordinator-layout-in-android

Comment: I suggest you keep track of it and when your new scrollY is 0 use old one. maybe it works because you can force set the scroll

Comment: Hey, it's been a while and I am still looking for a solution. Anyone has any idea? @PouyaDanesh